# check file existence without using os.Stat after locking the path

Tags: go, flock

When I lock a file path with `flock` then check the file existence it return no error even though there is no file in that path. The code follows:

```golang
filePath := filepath.Join(r.path, fmt.Sprintf("%s_event.json", eventId))

fileLock := flock.New(filePath)
fileLock.Lock()
defer fileLock.Close()

_, err = os.Stat(filePath)
if err != nil {
    if os.IsNotExist(errs) {
        return event, EventNotFound{}
    }   
    return
}
```

But when at first check the `Stat` then lock the file it works. I need to check it before that. Every idea is welcome!

Comment: What package is `flock`? Most likely that is creating the file for you if it does not yet exist.

Comment: hmmm it shouldn't:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/theckman/go-flock

Comment: https://github.com/gofrs/flock/blob/6f010d1acea74a32f2f2066bfe324c08bbee30e3/flock.go#L119

Comment: sounds bad! tnx, do you know any other way to lock the file without creating, because I require to do that for my save/load process.

Comment: please clarify your question - the package link in your comment differs from the one cited by @JimB

Comment: And also what OS you are running on, as file locking capabilities differ greatly by OS.

Comment: @colm.anseo: it's the same package, the repo was moved to a new username and redirects automatically.

Comment: @MaryamAbdoli, you can't lock a file that does not exist, create the file first (and remember that POSIX locks are only advisory, so all processes must cooperate in the locking)

Comment: Please note that the `syscall` package from stdlib exports the `Flock` function on *nix platforms. So if you don't need portability, you could just call it on your file. In either way, you can't have the logic as you intended: you need first to attempt to create the file (`os.OpenFile` with the `os.O_CREAT|os.O_EXCL` flags) and then try to `flock` it—no matter whether it existed or not.

Comment: To get better understanding of how this work, please read `open(2)` and `flock(2)` manual pages.